Расширение VSTO при подключении дает ошибку "....не является допустимой надстройкой Office."
Написал раcширение для Outlook в Visual Studio. Все хорошо работало, отключил его в Аутлуке от дебаговой паки, а потом, когда попробовал подключить получаю ошибку "*.dll  Office." То же самое и на другом компьютере.
Что нужно сделать, чтобы Office загружал расширение?
